# Movie Streaming Script

Tags: php

I want to develop a Movie information Database and Video Streaming website. I am wondering is there any off the shelf script available for the same ?

Please share some information regarding the same..

I would prefer it to a PHP script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's already a solution for this, but the steps to achieve something like you want are not that hard.

Here's what you need:

1. Backend for Storing and Delivering files (Simple CRUD) and basic database access
2. Cron or something like this to convert your uploaded Videos into FLV/HTML5 Video (see ffmpeg)
3. Frontend to display your encoded videos (see http://videojs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the html5 video tag